# nodemon in npm script triggered multiple times

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, npm-scripts

My npm scripts:

```
"build": "tsc -w -p ./src/server",
"run": "nodemon --watch ./dist/server ./dist/server/app.js",
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm:build\" \"npm:run\""
```

From VSCode's terminal I can start the app using the `start` task.

But nodemon starts twice, and restarts multiple times when a file is saved. I assumed it's because the `build` task hasn't completed yet.

How can I make these work in series, so the one waits for the other? I do not want to use polling.

I'm using Ubuntu 18, node 10.15.0, npm 6.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Example of my configuration which works well:

package.json:

```
"start:dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json ./dist/src/index.js",
```

nodemon.json:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
}
```